# How to apply LOWER() to a ref in Objection

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, knex.js, objection.js

Im using a `like` where statement in my query like this:

```js
import { ref } from 'objection'

// [...]

query = query.where(ref('data.nested_data').castText(), 'like', `%${value}%`)
```

And its working fine. The resulting query looks like this:

```sql
WHERE CAST("data"#>>'{nested_data}' AS text) like '%example%'
```

Now I want to use `LOWER()` funcion in the key, so I can find results case-insensitive. So my query now looks like this:

```js
import { ref, raw } from 'objection'

// [...]

query = query.where(raw(`LOWER(${ref('data.nested_data').castText()})`), 'like', `%${value.toLowerCase()}%`);
```

But this results to the following SQL query (throwing an error):

```sql
WHERE LOWER([object Object]) like $1

-- ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["
-- LINE 6: WHERE LOWER([object Object]) like $1
```

Is there any way to achieve what Im looking for? I prefer not using a raw query since my type to cast is dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The people maintaining Objection helped me solving this issue at [github](https://github.com/Vincit/objection.js/issues/2111#issuecomment-923716832).

The correct syntax is:

```
const key = ref('data.nested_data').castText();
query = query.where(raw('LOWER(??)', [key]), 'like', `%${value.toLowerCase()}%`);
```